# What is the most belated accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

One of my answers was accepted **6 years** later:

[Upload large files to BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679855/upload-large-files-to-blob/12969156#comment90788111_12969156)

Is there another accept that was belated even more?

Should there be some time limit for this?

Comment: That is still in the [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) range. I see no problem?

Comment: I am just curious if this is some kind of record

Comment: nope, it is not a record: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/888886

Comment: Nearly 10 years...? damn seasonal programmers...

Comment: @rene 88888... *6*??? Try harder next query. You're only 2 away from gr8ness.

Answer (score 24):

Most of this kind of curiosity can be answered with a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)<sup>1</sup> query, like [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/888886)

```sql
select top 100 
       p.id as [Post Link]
     , datediff(d, p.creationdate, v.creationdate) [# days till accept]
from posts p
inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
where v.votetypeid = 1 -- Accept
order by 2 desc
```

This query shows, when run today

> [How to redirect output of an entire shell script within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314675/how-do-i-redirect-the-output-of-an-entire-shell-script-within-the-script-itself/315113#315113)

as the top answer that got its accept 3,547 days after the question was asked.

And then you wonder:

> Should there be some time limit for this?

It is never too late to see the light ...

---

<sub>1. Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday morning. If you're new to SEDE you might like the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) and if you have additional questions, feel free to hop in [SEDE Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede)</sub>

Comment: For once I beat you to the punch, by [over a year](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/695493/answers-that-took-way-too-long-to-accept-all-users) even.

Comment: @BoltClock beating accepted ... :D